# C# Web API JSON string map to object

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a Web API method that receives a JSON object.

The JSON posted from the client is:

```
{
    "EmployerId": 1,
    "EmployeeId": 6,
    "HolidayTypeId": 1,
    "CategoryType": "Normal",
    "SelectedDates": {
        "Wed Jul 16 2014": "2014-07-16T00:00:00",
        "Thu Jul 17 2014": "2014-07-17T00:00:00",
        "Fri Jul 18 2014": "2014-07-18T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

The Web Method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateHolidayRequest([FromBody] Model.HolidayRequestModel request) {

    HttpResponseMessage returnVal = null;

    returnVal = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Model.Custom.JsonResponse {
        data = null,
            message = "",
            num = 1,
            success = true
    });

}
```

My `HolidayRequestModel` class is:

```
public class HolidayRequestModel {
    public int HolidayId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int EmployeeId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public byte HolidayTypeId {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Selected Dates
    public List<string> SelectedDates {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I get all the properties fine except `SelectedDates` because I just realize that is not a `List<string>` because the `SelectedDates` has a field and a value.

Any clue on what the `SelectedDates` property type should be in order to get it populated in my model?

Comment: I think the date format should be something like: `"SelectedDates": [
"2014-07-16T00:00:00"]`

Comment: You expect a List at SelectedDates but you posting JSON object {}. You should change the JSON to []

Comment: I dont have control on client code :(

Comment: You could create a custom Message Handler to change it to use [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `SelectedDates` property to be a `Dictionary<string, string>` (or possibly `Dictionary<string, DateTime>`) instead of a `List<string>`, and that will allow it to deserialize properly.

e.g.:

```
public class HolidayRequestModel {

    ...

    // Selected Dates
    public Dictionary<string, string> SelectedDates {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```